# Skip A TAG Having Same Class in Imacros

Tags: button, imacros

I have created a script which works fine, but i am just stuck on one issue that i cannot figure-out how to tackle it. So I wanted your help guys.

I just want to click a button but the thing is there are several buttons having the exact same class on the page. So the script does is it just clicks on the first button that it finds on the page. I want to skip that first button and click the second button.

So in short
button 1 <-- skip
button 2 <-- click

(both have same class="buttons")

below is the code

> ```
> TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:NEXT
> WAIT SECONDS=6
> TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=ID:knowledge-preregistered-email-response CONTENT={{!COL4}}
> TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:NEXT
> WAIT SECONDS=7
> TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=CLASS:yt-uix-button*yt-uix-button-size-default*yt-uix-button-default*yt-uix-button-empty*yt-uix-button-has-icon*no-icon-markup*comment-action-buttons-renderer-thumb*yt-uix-sessionlink*sprite-comment-actions*sprite-like*i-a-v-sprite-like*
> WAIT SECONDS=7
> ```

This is the button class

```
> ATTR=CLASS:yt-uix-button*yt-uix-button-size-default*yt-uix-button-default*yt-uix-button-empty*yt-uix-button-has-icon*no-icon-markup*comment-action-buttons-renderer-thumb*yt-uix-sessionlink*sprite-comment-actions*sprite-like*i-a-v-sprite-like*
```

So i want to skip the first button having this class and move on to the next one and click that.

Comment: Damn im so silly. I did it myself :) .. just changed TAG POS=1 to 2

Answer (score 0):

Damn im so silly. I did it myself :) .. just changed TAG POS=1 to 2